# Parsing the memory location of the source file of an ImageButton causes an error, why?

Tags: java, android, memory, string-parsing

## The ERROR I cannot justify

Say we have the memory location of a drawable (I stored that in a tag in the XML file) and we use it as a parameter for `setImageResource(MEMORY_LOCATION)`. I can't make it work as the function is waiting for an `int` as input and by the time I parse it... I get an error

---

[What I mean by memory location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SmSuy.png)

---

The exact point I do not understand is **Why does parsing a string representing a memory location to an int CAUSES AN ERROR?**

If you want to find out why I want this or can suggest another way of solving the problem please read the full description

---

## The problem I am trying to solve is to Find *source* from *id*

Say we have *n* ImageButtons and we want to pass their `drawable` to the next `Activity`.

One possible way would be using multiple case elements...

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public static int chosen_button;
private ImageButton image_Button_1;
private ImageButton image_Button_2;
...
private ImageButton image_Button_n;
private final int possible_Buttons[] = {R.drawable.imgbtn1,R.drawable.imgbtn2,...,R.drawable.imgbtnn};

private View.OnClickListener tweakedOnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId())
        {
            case R.id.imgbtn1:
                chosen_Button = possible_Buttons[0];
                break;
            case R.id.imgbtn2:
                chosen_Button = possible_Buttons[1];
                break;
            ...
            case R.id.imgbtnn:
                chosen_Button = possible_Buttons[n];
                break;
            default:
                throw new RuntimeException("Unknown button ID");
        }
        Intent activity_Main_To_Secondary = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondaryActivity.class);
        startActivity(activity_Main_To_Secondary);
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    image_Button_1 = findViewById(R.id.imgbtn1);
    image_Button_2 = findViewById(R.id.imgbtn2);
    image_Button_n = findViewById(R.id.imgbtnn);

    image_Button_1.setOnClickListener(tweakedOnClickListener);
    image_Button_2.setOnClickListener(tweakedOnClickListener);
    image_Button_n.setOnClickListener(tweakedOnClickListener);
}
}
```

Then in order to get the drawable (as the `ImageButton` is only wired to the `MainActivity` via the **XML** file and is not wired to the `SecondaryActivity` at all) we can simply call the public int `chosen_button` and it works!

But with multiple case statements and multiple lines of code...

---

### Another approach would be:

`v.getId()` gives the id, a  memory location (I guess pointing to the XML file?)

`R.drawable.triangle` gives the src, a memory location pointing to the png file.

So as there is no function returning the memory location of the `drawable` by taking the `id` in, I tried setting the tag in the XML section file in the `MainActivity` to the memory location of each drawable. Looks like this:

```
<ImageButton

    android:id="@+id/imgbtn1"
...
    android:tag="‭2130903048"
    <!-- Does it make any difference if it is written in hex, binary or decimal??? -->
    android:src="@drawable/imgbtn1"
```

Everything works from when you try to `v.getTag().toString()` in `MainActivity` but by the time I try to parse it to an Int (or `putExtra` to the intent linking main and secondary activities) then the app breaks leading to the question of my post.

```
Intent activity_Main_To_Draw = getIntent();
String mem_location = activity_Main_To_Secondary.getStringExtra("$mem_loc");
Integer.parseInt(mem_location)
```

Comment: In Android you’re working with view or resource IDs. Those are integer values. Don’t reason in terms of “memory locations”, it’s not relevant and makes no sense here.

Comment: So why can't I parse this string "2130903048" to an int?